# How do you export and load models with custom materials in three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl, maya, 3dsmax

How can I export a 3d model e.g. from Maya with custom materials, load them in three.js and apply all materials?

All examples that can be found on [threejs.org](http://threejs.org/examples/) are using hardcoded materials for the child elements of the geometry. Is there any library or 3d format to export custom materials with my own parameters and load them in three.js?

This seems to be a common problem in 3d programming. I guess I need to develop my own material editor for three.js if I want more complex 3d objects with more than *Lambert* or *Phong* materials.

Any thoughts?

Comment: many noob's are having the same problems unfortunately (myself included).  It seems to me the JSON loader may not be working correctly with the latest renditions to three.js as the materials are just not being applied correctly.  Hopefully somebody has a specific answer.

Comment: It might be possible to use the names of the materials exported with the OBJ file to apply your own materials. But this is just a workaround...